# Job offers per country with salary

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Just out of interest, are there any figures how likely it is that employers from certain countries tend to give a salary range for their job offer?

I as someone who occasionally looks for a job do find it very informative to see a salary range on an offer. As en example [in Germany 736 jobs are offered for developers](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=developer&l=germany&d=20&u=Km), but only [125 do show a salary range](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=developer&l=germany&d=20&u=Km&s=1&c=EUR).

So the discipline in Germany by employers appears to be around ~17%.

How is this in other countries around the world? Is it just a secret in Germany?

Comment: Why not look it up yourself?

Comment: You mean [here on data](https://data.stackexchange.com/) right? Because I don't know how, yet, and am currently lacking the time :)

Comment: I don't think this info is on the data explorer, no. At a quick glance, hings don't seem to look much different in other European countries...

Comment: And I would have a follow up question, which I am rather certain is not available that easy: How is the response ration of developers to offers with salary in contrast to those without.

Comment: They did a writeup on how responses differed in their own testing: https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/27/salary-transparency/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's a quick breakdown of common countries and the percentage of jobs with salaries:

```
Country     | % 
----------- | ------
US          | 22.7
Germany     | 15.4       
UK          | 48.0
Canada      | 20.8
France      | 50.0
```

Germany actually has a few more jobs than you've mentioned, hence the lower percentage.

Our sales reps try to get employers to provide salary, so the tide is turning (we're running at 24.3% over all jobs) but it's a long road :)

As Pekka 웃 mentioned we have a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/27/salary-transparency/) detailing how jobs with salaries get better results.